# Is there another way to download file in jquery or form submit?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, parameters, struts2

I want to download file via `window.open(url)` method, however parameters is so much that action can not receive them. Is there some solution to solve it in jQuery or via form submit?

```js
var url = "${path}/MaterialStockedAnalysisExport.action?type=byCompany";
url += "&startMonth=" + startMonth + "&endMonth=" + endMonth + "&materialStr=" +
    escape(encodeURIComponent(materialStr))  + "&companyStr=" + 
    escape(encodeURIComponent(companyStr));
alert(url);
window.open(url);
```

Comment: It works !! submit together with form. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters to the action could be passes in two ways, in the servlet technology is either http GET or POST request. But due some server or browser limitations of the navigator bar you couldn't pass all of them in one request. The solution to the problem is to make form `hidden` input fields, and submit the form.

```
<s:set var="myPath">${path}</s:set>  
<s:url var="myUrl" namespace="%{#myPath}" action="MaterialStockedAnalysisExport" />
<s:form id="myForm" action="%{myUrl}" method="POST">
  <s:hidden name="type"/>
  <s:hidden name="startMonth"/>
  <s:hidden name="endMonth"/>
  <s:hidden name="materialStr"/>
  <s:hidden name="companyStr"/>
  <s:a id="myLink" href="#">Export</s:a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myLink").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('input[name=type]').val('byCompany');
        $('input[name=startMonth]').val(startMonth);
        $('input[name=startMonth]').val(endMonth );
        $('input[name=materialStr]').val(ematerialStr);
        $('input[name=companyStr]').val(companyStr);
        $("#myForm").submit();
      });
    });
  </script>
</s:form>
```

Comment: It works !! submit together with form. Thanks for your exact answer (even have typed my origin parameters). Thanks for  your kindness!